# Actualizar Mysql funciona en Json y no en Android Studio

Tags: php, java, android, json

Soy nuevo en la programación espero puedan ayudarme con mi problema. Estoy realizando una aplicación donde busco recolectar el contenido de varios editar texto y actualizar mi DB con esos valores. el problema es que mi php funciona bien cuando lo pruebo en Postman, pero cuando lo pruebo con el código no actualiza. espero puedan ayudarme

```
public void Actualizar_info (){

        String Url_EDIT = "https://url/UsuariosRDC/Actualizar.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url_EDIT, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                    if (success.equals("1")){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Actualizado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error en actualizacion: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        })

        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("placa",placaVal.getText().toString());
                params.put("beneficio1",beneficio1v.getText().toString());
                params.put("beneficio2",beneficio2v.getText().toString());
                params.put("beneficio3",beneficio3v.getText().toString());
                params.put("beneficio4",beneficio4v.getText().toString());
                params.put("beneficio5",beneficio5v.getText().toString());
                params.put("beneficio6",beneficio6v.getText().toString());
                params.put("beneficio7",beneficio7v.getText().toString());
                params.put("beneficio8",beneficio8v.getText().toString());

                return params;

            }
        };

        request.add(stringRequest);
```

[image: Este es mi php:]

Comment: Recuerda que los datos en tu archivo los recibirás con el método `POST`, cambia los `_GET[]` por `_POST[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero en android estas creando una peticion  de tipo POST

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url_EDIT, new Response.Listener<String>()
```

pero en PHP estas tratando de obtener las variables por metodo GET, si quieres mantener eso entonces tendrias que mandar en la url los parametros.

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url_EDIT, new Response.Listener<String>()
```

la url seria:

```
 String Url_EDIT = "https://javicheti.000webhostapp.com/UsuariosRDC/Actualizar.php?placa"=+placaVal.getText().toString()+"&beneficio1="+,beneficio1v.getText().toString();
```

lo siguiente lo debes usar si quieres enviar parametros en la cabecera de la peticion:

```
 @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
```

Comment: Genial funciona! muchas gracias!!